# PHP in_array not working after loop in session

Tags: php, arrays

I have a `foreach` loop to check all array of `ID` and `if` using `in_array` to see if any of the arrays of `IDs`is equaled my `$_POST['id']` as shown below:

```
$cart = array (
    'title' => $_POST['title'],
    'price' => $_POST['price'],
    'img_src' => $_POST['img_src'],
    'id' => $_POST['id'],
   
    );

foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) {
   $id = $item['id'];
}

if(in_array($_POST['id'], $id)){
    
    echo "ID exist";
    
}else{
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $cart;
        $count = count($_SESSION["cart"]);

}
```

For some reason, it keeps adding even when the `ID` exist inside the list of arrays of `IDs`.

Comment: Please give us some more info. Where does `$id` come from and what does it contain? Do a `var_dump($id);` and add the output to the question for clarification. Also include a `var_dump($_POST)` so we can see what the actual data looks like. It's hard to help debugging code when you don't actually know what the variables you're using contains.

Comment: And to the upvoter, please don't upvote questions that are missing vital information.

Comment: sorry I just updated ```$id``` is from foreach loop ```foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) {
   $id = $item['id'];
}```

Comment: `$id` is only a single value, the last one from the `$_SESSION` array. You're just overwriting it over and over. Presumably it's not an array. Presumably you even get a notice about it from `in_array`, you're just not looking at your error log and have turned off error display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just changing the value of **$id** inside foreach loop. Try to store value in array. Refer the below code:

```
$cart = array (
    'title' => $_POST['title'],
    'price' => $_POST['price'],
    'img_src' => $_POST['img_src'],
    'id' => $_POST['id'],
   
    );
$id = array();
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) {
   $id[] = $item['id'];
}

if(in_array($_POST['id'], $id)){
    
    echo "ID exist";
    
}else{
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $cart;
        $count = count($_SESSION["cart"]);

}
```